# psinfo_t solaris does not contain full process name in its field

Tags: c++, c, unix, solaris, procfs

Not getting full process name in psinfo_t struct's field pr_fname while reading process info from psinfo data file(/proc/%d/psinfo) into struct psinfo_t from procfs.h in solaris.

Full psinfo_t struct definition is present on below site:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5174/6mbb98ui2/index.html

Only if the process name is less than equal to 15 characters then I am getting the full process name other wise if process name is more than 15 characters then I am getting only first 15 characters of process name rest characters are truncated.

The code I am using is as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <procfs.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // get the pid from command line
    int pid  = atoi(argv[1]);

    // create the pstatus struct from procfs
    psinfo_t info;

    char file[100];
    sprintf(file, "/proc/%d/psinfo", pid);
    ifstream in(file);
    if (in)
    {
        in.read((char*)&info, sizeof(psinfo_t));
        in.close();

        cout << "My Name: " << info.pr_fname << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Process Not Exists!" << endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Do I have to read some other file (other than psinfo) from procfs file system in order to get full process name.
Also if I am using belwo ps command from command line then I am able to get full process name:

```
ps -p 4970 -o comm
```

but I don't want to get process name by executing ps command inside my code.
I am curious from where ps binary is picking up the process name.

Answer (score 2):

The `pr_fname` field of the `psinfo_t` structure is 16 bytes long, per [the source code](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/procfs.h#240):

```
#define PRFNSZ      16  /* Maximum size of execed filename */
```

So it will in fact be truncated to a maximum of 15 characters.

You can get the the name of the actual binary file from `/proc/PID/map`.  For a 32-bit process the exec'd binary will be mapped at address `0x00010000`.

You can browse the source code for `ps` at http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/ps/ if you want to see where it finds its data.

Comment: is there a pre-defined struct in which I can store data of this map file.

Comment: @mSatyam It's on the same `proc.4` man page you linked in your question.

Comment: I tried reading the map data file into prmap_t struct but when I printed the data member pr_mapname it was an empty string. Did you intended me to do something else. Am I doing right?

Comment: How did you read the map data?  You pretty much need to read binary `prmap_t` structures from `/proc/pid/map` with one low-level `read()` call.

Comment: I read it the same way I read psinfo struct as in my question. Will try with low level read call now.

Answer (score 2):

Solaris 11.3 SRU 5 introduced `/proc/<pid>/execname` which contains the full command name, so you can check to see if that file exists and use it if so, else fall back to the limited `pr_fname`.

See [Solaris 11.3 SRU 5.6: updates in ps(1) and /proc/<pid>/{cmdline,environ,execname}](https://blogs.oracle.com/casper/entry/solaris_11_3_sru_5) for details.